# convert double value (indexed color) into int value - Android

Tags: android, image-processing, colors, bitmap

I have a problem when I tried to display an image. I have a 2D array of double values, and each value represents an indexed color in `RGB`.

I have to create a bitmap with each of the value of array 2D. I create a bitmap with this configuration:

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(DIMX, DIMY, Config.RGB_565);
```

and then seat each pixel value of bitmap using:

```
bm.setPixel(i, j, ¿?);
```

android documentation says that third parameter of set pixel method is an int value which represents a Color. and my questions is: how can I obtain int value from double value stored in 2d array?

Answer (score 0):

you can int type cast

```
Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(arrayWidth, arrayHeight,
                ARGB_8888);
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                // set newly-inverted pixel to output image
                bmOut.setPixel(x, y, (int)array[x][y]);
            }
        }
```

bmOut is your desired bitmap